# Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android

Tags: android, bitmap

I am continously having this problem and I don't know what to do about it.

I've used [this](https://github.com/dtitov/pickncrop) library and when I get the cropped image I save it in a static variable and move to the next activity. When I arrive in the next activity , I reference that static variable to get the bitmap and try to scale it down. But it gives me error.

Here's what I am doing.

```
public void buttonCropClick(View view) throws IOException
{
    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    imageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
    Snapshot.CroppedBitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache(true);
    imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    startActivity(new Intent(this,RecommendationInfo.class));
}
```

in the `RecommendationInfo` class , I get the bitmap in the following line `Snapshot.CroppedBitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache(true);` then I save this bitmap in the static variable which I reference in next activity and pass it to the following function.

```
public static Bitmap scaleDown(Bitmap realImage,boolean filter) {

    float maxImageSize = HeightToSet;
    float ratio = Math.min(
            (float) maxImageSize / realImage.getWidth(),
            (float) maxImageSize / realImage.getHeight());
    int width = Math.round((float) ratio * realImage.getWidth());
    int height = Math.round((float) ratio * realImage.getHeight());

    // Error here
    Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(realImage, width,height, filter);
    return newBitmap;
}
```

I already tried calling `bitmap.recycle()`. Why am I getting this problem what can I do to solve it ? Here's my logcat.

```
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653): java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to use a recycled bitmap android.graphics.Bitmap@4059b8b8
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:955)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1012)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:462)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:349)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at com.example.Libraries.Snapshot.scaleDown(Snapshot.java:42)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at com.example.androidtestproject.RecommendationInfo.SetRecommendationValues(RecommendationInfo.java:195)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at com.example.androidtestproject.RecommendationInfo.access$5(RecommendationInfo.java:183)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at com.example.androidtestproject.RecommendationInfo$1.onClick(RecommendationInfo.java:154)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2552)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9229)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:138)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
07-14 03:09:43.713: E/AndroidRuntime(19653):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-14 03:09:45.515: E/TAG(20039): End of input at character 0 of
```

Comment: What error it gave you ?

Comment: I've updated the question please check

Comment: your bitmap is recycled somewhere,  you can't call the bitmap after you recycle it. please see if you recycling the bitmap or not before starting the other activity.

Comment: add `if (newBitmap != realImage) {realImage.recycle(); realImage = newBitmap ;} System.gc();` after `createScaledImage`, and as k0sh mentioned.. make sure you don't recyle the bitmap in the first place before proccing it to the next activity.

Comment: still getting the same error. I tried your code

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Copy the bitmap before you pass it to the static variable.

```
Snapshot.CroppedBitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache(true);
```

to

```
Snapshot.CroppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache(true));
```

It is very likely that the imageView is recycling its drawing cache when no longer needed as good practice. By copying it out, you keep a reference to the bitmap the ImageView trashed. Just make a copy of it that you can manage yourself!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504314/trying-to-use-a-recycled-bitmap-in-android-gives-error same error is coming in my code what i have to change for this

Answer (score 3):

You need to copy the source image first:

```
Bitmap bitmap = webview.getDrawingCache();
if (bitmap != null) {
        Snapshot.CroppedBitmap.setImageBitmap(bitmap.copy(bitmap.getConfig(), false));
}
```

- Using createBitmap will not necessarily create a copy of the source bitmap, resulting the same error.

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't copy a recycled bitmap

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have to copy previous bitmap to new bitmap and set mutable to true. that it.

> ```
> Bitmap copy = previousBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
> ```

Now i can perform new operation on bitmap.